# Dealing with html and NLTK

Tags: python, html, nltk

i'm trying to deal HTML with NLTK.
First i load all files with PlaintextCorpusReader:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus_root = 'C:\corpus\'
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
```

Now how can i deal the HTML using the functions like 'urlopen(url).read()'?
Or there's another way to deal with it (like read all the files in that corpus_root and process the HTML files)?

Comment: plaintextcorpusreader only reads plaintext not html. you have to clean the htmls before using NLTK.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach A:** if you want to deal with HTML that is found only in .html files, then you can simply identify those with `html_files = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root,'.*\.html')` and then use BeautifulSoup or lxml (or urllib that you seem to like) to read from strings to create DOM objects. For example:

```
from lxml import etree

for htm in html_files:
     dom = etree.fromstring(htm)

     #any further manipulations, e.g.:
     content = dom.cssselect('#content')        # you can also use cssselect to take all links or whatever
     maintext = content[0].text    # in case there are no other embedded tags in this one
```

**Approach B:** if you are dealing with 'mixed' files with both plain text and html parts, then I suppose the only way is to use regular expressions to extract the html parts based on tags, e.g.: `htm_part = re.findall('<.*?>.*?</.*?>',yourdoc,re.DOTALL)`. This will likely return a list especially if the files are long, so you can do `''.join(htm_part)` as the next step. After extracting only html parts you can go ahead and try lxml or BeautifulSoup again to create DOM objects to work more with it, as described above. If it breaks then most probably regexp is getting something wrong and you'll have to fine-tune. Hope this helps.